# Positioning nodes relative to nodes of binary tree layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I found out that relative positioning doesn't work, if I use a graph layout. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
    graphdrawing
  , graphs
  , positioning
  }
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[binary tree layout]
        \graph {
            n0 -> {n1, n2};
        };
        \node [left = of n0] {left of n0};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following unexpected output.

[image]

Pretty much anything placement related doesn't work. You can say `at (n0.center)`, the last node will end up in the same place. How I can place nodes relative to the nodes in the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `binary tree layout` to the `tikzpicture` environment. If you move it to an option that is passed to `\graph`, like this: `\graph[binary tree layout]`, your code works.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
    graphdrawing
  , graphs
  , positioning
  }
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}%[binary tree layout]
        \graph[binary tree layout] {
            n0 -> {n1, n2};
        };
        \node[left= of n0] {left of n0};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ha! Who would know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make this with the trees library. You can position the nodes by giving nodes the name of the node.

The code is

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
      level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm}]
      \node (n0) {n0}
        child {node (n1) {n1}}
        child {node (n2) {n2}
        };
    
        \node [left of=n0, xshift=-1cm] {left of n0};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is as

[image: tree output]

Comment: Please, check the title. The question was about binary tree layout. If you don't use a binary tree layout, you don't need even trees, quite regular sequence of \node, child will have the same effect as in your picture. Names of the nodes are irrelevant.